# What does com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(Config) do?

Tags: scala, typesafe, typesafe-config

What does the method `load(Config)` in class `com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory` do? How would the output Config be different from the input Config?

The [documentation](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load-com.typesafe.config.Config-) says that it:

> Assembles a standard configuration using a custom Config object rather than loading "application.conf". The Config object will be sandwiched between the default reference config and default overrides and then resolved.

I do not understand what it is saying.

The code shows that:

```java
public static Config load(Config config) {
    return load(checkedContextClassLoader("load"), config);
}
```

It seems to be loading with a `checkedContextClassLoader` which I don't understand. Can someone give a short understandable explanation of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would the output Config be different from the input Config?

It has the reference config (loaded from `reference.conf`) as fallback for anything not defined in the input `Config`, and then overrides from system properties are applied ("Future versions may get overrides in more places. It is not guaranteed that this method only uses system properties.").

> It seems to be loading with a checkedContextClassLoader which I don't understand.

I don't think this is an important part. This is simply the default classloader used by the library.